# Circuit simulation software source with ground and without ground

Tags: voltage, simulations, batteries

Many circuit simulation softwares require a circuit to have ground. In my opinion, this distorts simulation. For example, let us take a simple circuit with 12V DC source (battery) and resistor. Here we have two electric fields, one formed by a positive terminal and one formed by a negative terminal. These two fields determine the voltage. Now if we add a ground to this circuit the negative terminal effectively disappears, since ground has no charge. So the voltage has to change. Are my concerns relevant? If they are relevant that how one can accommodate for it (we can use multisim as an example).

Answer (score 2):

Potential it's defined up to an additive constant, that additive constant can be zero if we choose it to be, but it could not. What makes an electric field exist is a potential difference.

Ground is what we reference our circuits to: when we say that we have $5V$ we're saying that the potential difference from the reference point, which may or may not be ground, is $5V$. Positive and negative terminals do not create an electric field by themselves. Beside the fact that we cannot define a positive or negative terminal if we don't have a reference.

If I have a reference ground, a $10V$ terminal and a $5V$ terminal they are both at a positive potential with respect to ground. But if now I say that the reference is that $5V$ terminal we have indeed a positive $5V$ which was the $10V$ terminal before and a $-5V$ which was the ground terminal before.

See, we cannot talk about a potential in an absolute manner, there will always be that additive term.

Comment: What do you mean "we cannot define a positive and negative terminal if we do not have a reference." We take cloth and plastic and rub it together. One of them will have an excess of electrons (negative terminal) and other will have shortage of electrons (positive terminal).

Comment: Yes, that's true that there will be a net negative (positive) charge on the cloth (plastic). But what we're talking here is negative potential. Potential energy is always defined up to some constant. If you don't have a potential difference you cannot have and electric field and you can easily see by $$E = -\nabla V$$ where the electric field, which is what moves the charges around in a conductor, is generated by a gradient of a potential. When we say that a battery has $9V$ we're implicitly saying that the potential difference between it's two connector is $9V$.

Comment: I do not understand this "up to some constant". If we are talking about work done between two points, there is no additive constant anymore. Additive constant accounts for reference point, one reference point is fixed and clear, there is no more a constant. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, when you choose one, everything is fixed. See choosing a ground reference as choosing a specific constant. But the ground reference is not unique nor it's the additive constant. This explains the example of the $10V$ circuit i gave you before.